# Absolute value inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

for any : $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Prove that if  $|b−{a\over 2}|  < {|a|\over 2}$ so  $|b-a|<|a|$

I know that if $a>0 ⇒0<b<a$ and if $a<0 ⇒ a<b<0$

Trying without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **triangular inequality**: $|x+y| \le |x| + |y|$

Now:

$|b-a| = |(b - \frac{a}{2}) - \frac{a}{2}| \le |b- \frac{a}{2}| + |-\frac{a}{2}| = | b- \frac{a}{2}| + |\frac{a}{2}| \le  |\frac{a}{2}| + |\frac{a}{2}| = |a|$

Where last inequality is based on assumption that $|b - \frac{a}{2}|\le \frac{a}{2}$